# How to get the iterator of a list of type <T> in C++?

Tags: c++, g++

I'm beginning with C++ and I'm struggling with templates.

Basically, I have this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

// ...

template <typename T>
void some_function(const list<T>& l) {
  // ...
  list<T>::iterator iter = l.begin();
  // ...
}
```

This line, in "some_function" creates an error at compile time:

```
./some_file.cpp:42:20: error: expected ';' after expression
  list<T>::iterator iter = l.begin();
                   ^
                   ;
./some_file.cpp:42:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'iter'
  list<T>::iterator iter = l.begin();
                    ^
./some_file.cpp:42:3: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'list<SomeObject>::iterator'
  list<T>::iterator iter = l.begin();
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I don't understand the keyword `typename` so I tried this:

```cpp
typename list<T>::iterator iter = l.begin();
```

but it tells me the type of `l.begin()` is not compatible with `typename list<SomeObject>::iterator`.

Basically, how can I get the iterator of a `std::list` of type `T` in C++?

> **NOTE**: I'm using C++ 20 and I compile using `g++`

Comment: -> `typename list<T>::const_iterator iter = l.begin();` or just `auto iter = l.begin();`.

Comment: an `iterator` allows you do modify the element. `const` containers can only give you `const_iterator`s

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai not exactly true.  For const containers, `iterator` and `const_iterator` are the same.

Comment: Ok thank you I didn't know about `const_iterator`

Comment: It works though :)

Comment: If you use C++20, just use `auto iter = l.begin();` - save yourself the fuss